# SSL packet transmission over TCP socket

Tags: python, ssl, tcp, server, client

I've got a TCP socket: the simplest client-server application.

First question: How can I generate a self-signed and non-self-signed SSL packet in Python?

Second question: How can I transfer SSL packets from the client to the server?

Programming language is python.

Server Code:

```
import socket
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

Client side code:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
    data = s.recv(1024)

print('Received', repr(data))
```

Comment: Welcome, there's [`ssl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) module, which provides features you're asking for. Take a look on docs.

Comment: I think that this question is too broad for StackOverflow. Once you've dug through documentation and tuturials, you can always come back here with specific problemms.

Comment: Both Python internal `ssl` module or well known external `pyopenssl` have detailed documentation and examples of simple TLS clients/servers. Also, if you are serious about security, it is not just a matter of putting TLS (SSL died 20 years ago) everything and think your job is finished. Security is not a product you can add later on a stack of features, it has to be thought from the beginning. TLS provide some features security-wise but they can all be ruined if not used/managed properly. Creating and handling certificates for one, is a big topic by itself.